# ASP.NET Core MVC @model breaking website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I am building a website using ASP.NET Core MVC. I have a view which is being rendered inside _layout.cshtml. I am trying to use a view model in the view, but when I insert at the beginning of the view `@model DocumentsViewModel` I get a http 500 error upon loading the view. Below is the code for the view.

```
@model DocumentsViewModel
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Training Documents";
}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 nopadding">
    <div class="nav navbar-defualt navbar-fixed">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
          <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="TrainingDocs" class="active"> Training Documents</a></li>
          <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="HumanResources"> Human Resources</a></li>
          <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="EmployeeForms"> Employee Forms</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-10 nopadding">
    <h1>Training Docs</h1>

    <div id="fileDiv">

    </div>

    <form method="post" asp-action="TrainingDocsUp" asp-controller="App" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="files" class="fileinput-label"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Choose a document ...
      <input type="file" name="files" class="my-inputfile" id="files" multiple/>
      </label>

      <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Upload" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: w/o providing the exception, we can't really help you other then **guessing**

Answer (score 2):

try using the fully qualified name of the viewmodel

```
@model ABC.XYZ.DocumentsViewModel
```

where ABC.XYZ is the namespace in which your view model exists. Alternatively, you can also use the using statement to import the namespace, so that **DocumentsViewModel** will be resolved.